# Get row number of an item in an indexed view of a SQLite table

Tags: sqlite

I have this simple table

`CREATE TABLE MyTable (MyText TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE);`

I have this SELECT statement that returns the table rows by descending order of their creation:

`SELECT MyText FROM MyTable ORDER BY rowid DESC;`

Let's say, it returns

```
A
B
C
```

How can I get the position of "B" (2 in this case) in this query result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer chatting with my friend RaptorX:

```
WITH SortedTable AS (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY rowid DESC) AS RowNum,
           MyText
      FROM MyTable
)
SELECT RowNum
  FROM SortedTable
 WHERE MyText = 'C';
```

or this one-line version:

`SELECT RowNum FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY rowid DESC) AS RowNum, MyText FROM MyTable) WHERE MyText = 'C';`